# SQL Anywhere (12) - Left Join, not distinct/unique enough?

Tags: sql, left-join, distinct, sqlanywhere

Sorry for the poor title, not sure how to word it better.

I'm trying to throw out any instance of a parent that has a child which contains x,y, or z

```
SELECT P.label, P.creationclass, P.attributes, P.type, P.uniqueid, C.label, C.idx, C.PID, C.creationclass, C.attributes, C.type, C.uniqueid
FROM t_equip_template AS P
LEFT JOIN t_equip_template AS C
ON P.ID = C.PID  //only way to join these
WHERE P.type = '1003'
AND    
C.creationclass NOT LIKE x
AND
C.creationclass NOT LIKE y
AND 
C.creationclass NOT LIKE z;
```

To further explain, my result set removes the instances where something is

```
 C.creationclass NOT LIKE [x y or z]
```

but this is not distinct enough since there are instances where the above is true but I still get a result that contains a P.ID in which one of its children do in fact have x,y,z true (though they are not shown in the resulting list). I'd rather the entire thing be thrown out and not just an 'instance where x,y,z is or is not true'

Since this is my only way of joining the two tables

```
P.ID = C.PID
```

I still get instances of P.ID that I do not want.

Is there a way to incorporate 'P.uniqueid' and if 'x,y,z' is or is not true of 'P.ID = C.PID' then throw out P.uniqueid, and not just that specific instance of 'C.PID'/'P.uniqueid'?

Thanks for the help.

Example:

```
 P.ID  P.uniqueid  C.PID  C.creationclass   
 1     00001       1      w  <--There is a 'hidden result' x,y or z for this    
 1     00001       1      v  <--There is a 'hidden result' x for this
 1     00001       1      u  <--There is a 'hidden result' x for this              
 2     00002       2      w
 2     00002       2      v
 3     00003       3      w
 3     00003       3      v
```

What I want is:

```
 P.ID  P.uniqueid  C.PID  C.creationclass   

 2     00002       2      w
 2     00002       2      v
 3     00003       3      w
 3     00003       3      v
```

The result I want throws out every instance of 00001 not onyl the specific instances that fail the criteria.

Solution, thanks to @JohnBollinger

```
        SELECT
        P.label,
        P.creationclass,
        P.attributes,
        P.type,
        P.uniqueid,
        C.label,
        C.idx,
        C.PID,
        C.creationclass,
        C.attributes,
        C.type,
        C.uniqueid
        FROM
        t_equip_template AS P
        LEFT JOIN t_equip_template AS C
        ON P.ID = C.PID
        WHERE
        P.type = '1003'
        AND

        AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM
          t_equip_template AS C2
        WHERE
          P.ID = C2.PID
          AND (C2.creationclass  LIKE x
               OR C2.creationclass  LIKE y           
               OR C2.idx LIKE z )
        )
```

Comment: Do you mean that a parent may have multiple children, and you want to exclude parents who have *any* child that satisfies your criteria?

Comment: It might be helpful if you add a sample data set and the desired result to your question.

Comment: what is `sql anywhere (12)` is a db product? for sql questions include sample data and desire output.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, exactly. Sample data coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do what you ask:

```
SELECT
  P.label,
  P.creationclass,
  P.attributes,
  P.type,
  P.uniqueid,
  C.label,
  C.idx,
  C.PID,
  C.creationclass,
  C.attributes,
  C.type,
  C.uniqueid
FROM
  t_equip_template AS P
  LEFT JOIN t_equip_template AS C
    ON P.ID = C.PID
WHERE
  P.type = '1003'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM
      t_equip_template AS C2
    WHERE
      P.ID = C2.PID
      AND (C2.creationclass LIKE x
           OR C2.creationclass LIKE y
           OR C2.creationclass LIKE z)
  )
```

You cannot do it with any join or filter condition that considers only a single row of the join result, because the information by which you want to filter is a function of multiple rows.

Comment: Thanks you very much John! Had to make a few changes, only due to a lack of detail in my original post. Also had to change the  last where clauses from C.creationclass to C2.creationclass

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to use `NOT EXISTS` (assuming that SQLAnywhere allows that syntax).

```
SELECT
    P.label,
    P.creationclass,
    P.attributes,
    P.type,
    P.uniqueid,
    C.label,
    C.idx,
    C.PID,
    C.creationclass,
    C.attributes,
    C.type,
    C.uniqueid
FROM
    t_equip_template AS P
LEFT JOIN t_equip_template AS C ON P.ID = C.PID
WHERE
    P.type = '1003' AND
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            t_equip_template C
        WHERE
            C.PID = P.PID AND
            C.creationclass IN (x, y, z)
    )
```